# Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' to custom User Class using new Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to query for a specific user using the new Firebase like so:

```
DataService.sharedInstance.REF_USERS.queryOrderedByChild("username").queryEqualToValue(field.text).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

                if let userDoesNotExist = snapshot.value as? NSNull {
                    print("No User found!")


                } else {
                    let theUsr = snapshot.value as! User
                    print(theUsr)


                }
            }, withCancelBlock: { (error) in
                    // Error

            })
```

From there I was looking to store the snapshot into its own object and access its values from there. I was attempting to do so by doing this:

```
class User {

    let key: String!
    let ref: FIRDatabaseReference?
    var username: String!
    var email: String!


    // Initialize from data snapshot
    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        key = snapshot.key
        email = snapshot.value!["email"] as! String
        username = snapshot.value!["username"] as! String
        ref = snapshot.ref
    }

    func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
        return [
            "email": email,
            "username": username,
        ]
    }

}
```

The problem I'm running into is a crash with the following:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x10239efc0) to 'Scenes.User' (0x100807bf0).
```

How do I fix this? I don't remember running into this problem on the old Firebase. I need access to the snapshot.value's key and for some reason can't access it by using snapshot.value.key without getting a crash so I figure I'd try passing all the data into it's own object.

Comment: You need to access each children individually like this snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("title").value as! String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

snapshot.value isn't a User, it's a dictionary (*)

Here's a couple of options - there are many.

```
let aUser = User()
aUser.initWithSnapshot(snapshot)
```

then, within the User class, map the snapshot.values to the user properties

or

```
let aUser = User()
aUser.user_name = snapshot.value["user_name"] as! String
aUser.gender = snapshot.value["gender"] as! String
```

Oh, and don't forget that by using .Value your snapshot may return multiple child nodes so those will need to be iterated over

```
for child in snapshot.children {
  let whatever = child.value["whatever"] as! String
}
```

In your case it's just one user so it's fine they way you have it.

*It could be

```
NSDictionary
NSArray
NSNumber (also includes booleans)
NSString
```